# No adding entity in a manytoone relationship using spring boot and jpa

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new in spring boot, I'm looking for help with this problem: I have two entities connected by a **ManytoOne relationship**. The entities are course and professor.

The professor Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "professor")
public class Professor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idProfessor;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String mail;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professor", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Course> courses;


    public Professor() {

    }

    public Long getIdProfessor() {
        return idProfessor;
    }

    public void setIdProfessor(Long idProfessor) {
        this.idProfessor = idProfessor;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

}
```

The Course Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCourse;
    private String title;
    private String description;

     @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="professor_id")
        private Professor professor;

     @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
        private List<Student> students;

    public Course() {}

    public Long getIdCourse() {
        return idCourse;
    }

    public void setIdCourse(Long idCourse) {
        this.idCourse = idCourse;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

I also created a rest controller to create Course and I defined POST endpoint like this:

```
@PostMapping(value="/create")
    public Course createCourse(@RequestBody Course course) {
        return courseRepo.save(course);
        }
```

When I add a new course in postman, the course is added but it is not assigned to the corresponding professor (an existing professor in the database), `"idProfessor"` is always assigned to NULL. Here is an example of POST API execution in postman and the result in MySQL.

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AAtv.jpg)

[mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbuc1.jpg)

Any suggestions?